# in python 3 ,difference in string input 'python' &python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>>str1 = input('enter the string : ')

>>>enter the string : learningpython

>>>str1.isalpha()

>>>true
>>>str2 = input('enter the string : ')

>>>enter the string : 'learningpython'

>>>str2.isalpha()

>>>false
```

When I use `input()` to take an input string, `isalpha()` reports that it contains alphabetic characters if I pass the string without quotes, but it does not if I use quotes. Why does this happen?

Comment: `'` is not an alphabetic character.

Comment: yeah that's right , str[0] is providing the result " ' " .

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If you type a character as part of the input, that character becomes part of the resulting string.  (Perhaps you are thinking of Python 2.x, where `input()` accepted Python expressions, so you did have to quote your input strings.)

Comment: Also, because you might be confused on this point: `isalpha` doesn't test if the string _contains any_ alphabetic characters; it tests whether _all of the characters_ of the string are alphabetic.

Answer (score 0):

.isalpha() checks if **all** characters are letters. When you enter 'learningpython' the string is exactly that, which includes quotations. You can see this easily by printing str2

```
>>>>print(str2)
'learningpython'
```

vs.

```
>>>>print(str1)
learningpython
```